# Как в background сразу зажать  градиент и изображения

Tags: css3

Как в background сразу зажать  градиент и изображения. Надо что то, по типу этого

```
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #ffffff 100%)  url(../images/all_photo.png) 20px 5px no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените проценты на px, пример

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FEFCEA 10px, #F1DA36 20px) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```